# sql FROM_UNIXTIME и date() php - час разницы

Tags: php, sql

В общем нужно в базе в колонках изменить дату, с UNIX в нормальную.

Пробую так

```
Дата в колонке date: 1477903122
UPDATE `order` SET `date` = FROM_UNIXTIME(date) where `id` = 698;
```

Мне обновляет запись на дату: 2016-10-31 **10**:38:42

А если через php вывожу дату, то выводит: 2016-10-31 **11**:38:42

Сервера стоят на одной тачке, пхп и апач.

```
select current_timestamp();// Выводит: 2016-10-31 11:38:52
```

Хотелось бы, что бы в sql изменяло на дату как в php, ибо в php пишет верную...

Comment: Покурите перевод часов на летнее время?

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL есть конфигурационный параметр `default-time-zone`, который содержит часовой пояс по умолчанию. Поменять его можно в конфиге MySQL или установить командами

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Первая команда устанавливает часовой пояс для всего сервера MySQL и требует привилегию `SUPER`. Вторая команда устанавливает часовой пояс для текущего соединения. Посмотреть их значения можно командой

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

В PHP есть конфигурационный параметр `date.timezone`. Изменить его можно либо в конфиге PHP, либо установить для текущего скрипта функцией `date_default_timezone_set`. Посмотреть текущее значение функцией `date_default_timezone_get`

Часовые пояса определенные в MySQL и PHP Должны совпадать.

К слову - цитата из документации PHP

> Начиная с версии PHP 5.1.0 (когда функции даты/времени были переписаны), вызов любой функции даты времени генерирует **E_NOTICE**, если временная зона имеет неверное значение, и/или **E_WARNING**, если используются системные параметры или переменная окружения `TZ`.